# SCSS Undefined variable: "$general-grey" but the variable is actually defined and different

Tags: css, sass, yarnpkg, roots-sage

I'm pretty new to this and I was tasked to update the Roots Sage Theme we use for our website to the latest version. Now, the conversion process isn't hard itself, however, when importing the header into the new theme folder and compiling with `yarn run build` I get this error:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                                                                                                                                                                                            12:29:21

error  in ./resources/assets/styles/main.scss

Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed:
      color: $general_grey;
            ^
      Undefined variable: "$general-grey".
      in /home/html/devel/website-folder/wp-content/themes/website-theme/resources/assets/styles/layouts/_header.scss (line 33, column 14)
```

As you can see, it says there is an undefined variable at line 33, column 14 called `$general-grey`. However, that is incorrect, as the variable is defined in a `_variables.scss` file and imported through `@import "common/variables";` in the `main.scss` file.

These are the lines where the color variables are defined in `_variables.scss`:

```
$theme-colors: (
  primary: #525ddc,
  brand_primary: #00add3,
  brand_darken: #0083a0,
  general_grey: #3d3d3d,
  overlay_text: #fff,
  std_black: #000,
  breadcrumb: #bababa,
  arancione: #f7941d,
  arancione_hover: #ab6614,
  verde: #90dd00,
  azzurro: #50c9e2,
  color-donne: #da6b93,
  grey_strong: #abbdc9
);
```

And this is the `_header.scss` file where I try to use the `general_grey` variable:

```
.green_number {
      font-family: $font-family-sans-serif;
      font-size: 12px;
      font-weight: 600;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: $general_grey;
      margin: 0;

      a {
        color: $general_grey;
      }

      .fa-phone,
      .green {
        color: $verde;
      }
    }
```

In both `_variables.scss` and `_header.scss` it's called `$general_grey` with an **underscore**, while the ERROR says the undefined variable in line 33, column 14 is `$general-grey`  with a **dash**.

Probably due to my inexperience, but I can't really get through this.
What could possibly cause this error?

Thank you in advance for the tips! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$theme-colors` is an [Advanced Variable Functions](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables#advanced-variable-functions). So to access to `general_grey` variable you will have to use the following:

```css
color: map.get($theme-colors, "general_grey");
```

Comment: The syntax you suggested me didn't seem to work. However, from that point I tried ti just write ' color: $theme-colors, "general_grey"; ' and it worked just fine! So thank you very much! :D